# Change Recipient Address Google Apps Script

Tags: google-app-engine, email, google-apps-script, gmail

Is it possible to change the recipient address when using the reply function in Google Apps Script?

I want to receive an email from a random email account, mark it with a label and when scheduled, run the following code to reply to a desired email address rather than the original sender. The reason I want to reply is to keep it in the same thread. I have tried nearly all variations of the following code and can't get it to work the way I want it to:

```
thread.reply("This is a message.", {
    htmlBody: "This is a message.",
    name: "My Name",
    recipient: "DESIRED@EMAIL.com",
    replyTo: "DESIRED@EMAIL.com",
    to: "DESIRED@EMAIL.com"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking to generate a random email address and send a real email from that address... that's not possible.

However... you could set the `replyTo` optional parameter as a random address - though when users would try to reply to that thread they would get a bounce-back notification that the address could not be reached. However, the original sender (the non-random address) would still be visible in the **original** message.

If you look at the **GmailApp docs** [(replying)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#reply%28String,Object%29)/[(sending)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29), you'll notice a few limitations. The sender's address (`from`) must be a valid [`Alias`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getAliases%28%29), if you're sending mail from *MailApp* (Google Apps Script).

However, there are plenty of methods in the `GmailMessage` class such as `getFrom()` and `getReplyTo()` that would allow you to *get/set the message's `from`/`replyTo` parameters* and have them be the same value. That way, when you reply to a message you will always be in the same thread.

Comment: Thanks for the response...
A use case for what I'm trying to do is the following: I receive an email; mark it with a label; "reply" event is triggered at a later date where the email is sent to an email address of my choosing, NOT the original sender's address (as a typical reply would do). Thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately the only real option you have is to *forward* the message. There is no way to "reply to a new person" and keep that message in the original thread. You can, however, forward the message with optional parameters: [see here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#forward%28String,Object%29). I haven't tested it, but if you set the `replyTo` parameter on the forwarded message to be the original sender of the thread, if the person replied to the forwarded message it would still be in the same thread (in your perspective). Don't hold me to it though!

Comment: This is exactly what I thought. Unfortunately, it's not working as desired. I'm trying to create the Boomerang for Gmail effect of returning an email to the top of the inbox at a later date, but this doesn't seem to be the correct approach.

Comment: I did notice another question you had posted on the subject. Manually testing it, without code, here's what I noticed. If you reply to the owner of the inbox (look again at `Alias` as shown in my answer), with the original message, the message comes back to the user's inbox at the top, unread. The same behavior occurs if you forward the message to the owner of the inbox. Those messages are also kept in the same thread. I know Boomerang - if you're looking for "bouncing back" messages after X time, you should forward/reply to the original message sender. At least, that works manually.

Comment: And also note - if you have that Label you apply *skipping the inbox (archiving)*, then no matter what you do, when you reply/forward that thread will have the *same Label*. So if you want it to go back to the inbox like a "notification", you need to remove the label from the message before sending, or create an entirely new message. To remove a label from a Thread: [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#removeLabel%28GmailLabel%29)

Comment: Exactly as I see it. Unfortunately, I'm unable to reply to the owner, but rather the original sender. And when I forward to the owner, a new thread is created. That's why I was trying to figure out a way to change the reply recipient address.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a limitation of Gmail in general, not just Apps Script. Because of the way that Gmail handles thread organization, when you `reply` to a new address you don't include the original thread. You can get all original recipients by iterating through each message in the thread and using the `getTo()` function to make a list of all original people in the conversation... but I'm not sure that meets your need. That's the only work-around I can think of, and if the owner isn't a member of the conversation that it will always create a new thread anyway.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help. I'll continue to work at it and post if I find what I'm looking for. This makes me even more curious about how Boomerang is able to achieve this feature, but oh well.

Comment: Boomerang is a browser extension, and not GAS-based. I don't develop browser plugins, but my guess is that there is a "more powerful API" that Google offers developers for the Google Chrome browser, one that likely integrates with Gmail (since it's all Google software)